# Sonarlint Issues and Log Tab not showing up on Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I installed the Sonar lint on Webstorm, restart Webstorm and then Activate Sonarlint Window from Tools Window. However, I am not seeing the Issues Tab and Log Tab showing up. The only thing I see is the Sonar lint console. How can I make Issues Tab and Log Tab to show up according to the screenshot found in http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/?

Comment: Please try to update to SonarLint v1.3 (the latest available in the jetbrains repository). The screenshot was taken from 1.3-RC and perhaps you were using v1.2.

Comment: Yes. I was using 1.2. Now, it works after I installed 1.3. Thanks.